# Previous highest value less than x with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a column to assign a comparison score (`baseScore`) to help provide better understanding of individual test scores.

The current `df` without the `baseScore` column is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                           ['2020-07-04 00:00:00', 0.64, 0.77, np.nan], 
                           ['2020-07-05 00:00:00', 0.86, 0.53, np.nan], 
                           ['2020-07-06 00:00:00', 0.79, 0.82, 0.71],
                           ['2020-07-07 00:00:00', 0.67, 0.85, np.nan], 
                           ['2020-07-08 00:00:00', 0.72, 0.91, 0.46], 
                           ['2020-07-09 00:00:00', 0.59, 0.63, np.nan],
                           ['2020-07-10 00:00:00', 0.71, 0.72, 0.69], 
                           ['2020-07-11 00:00:00', 0.42, 0.68, 0.80],
                           ['2020-07-12 00:00:00', 0.76, 0.70, np.nan],
                           ['2020-07-13 00:00:00', 0.53, 0.81, np.nan]
                           ]),
                   columns=['datetime', 'predictedScore', 'testScore', 'classAvg'])
    

df['testScore'] = pd.to_numeric(df['testScore'], errors='coerce')
df['classAvg'] = pd.to_numeric(df['classAvg'], errors='coerce')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

I am seeking to get the highest `'classAvg'` from the pre-existing rows which is less than the current `'testScore'` and not greater than previous `'testScore'` leading upto current row.
To better demonstrate the logic, below shows the desired output:

**Desired Output:**

```
    datetime predictedScore  testScore  classAvg  baseScore
0 2020-07-04           0.64       0.77       NaN        NaN
1 2020-07-05           0.86       0.53       NaN        NaN
2 2020-07-06           0.79       0.82      0.71        NaN
3 2020-07-07           0.67       0.85       NaN       0.71
4 2020-07-08           0.72       0.91      0.46       0.71
5 2020-07-09           0.59       0.63       NaN       0.46
6 2020-07-10           0.71       0.72      0.69       0.46
7 2020-07-11           0.42       0.68      0.80       0.46
8 2020-07-12           0.76       0.70       NaN       0.46
9 2020-07-13           0.53       0.81       NaN       0.46
```

Explanation for results in column `'baseScore'` from *Desired Output*:

`baseScore` index row 0 = `NaN` because there are no pre-existing `'classAvg'`

`baseScore` index row 1 = `NaN` because there are no pre-existing `'classAvg'`

`baseScore` index row 2 = `NaN` because there are no pre-existing `'classAvg'`

`baseScore` index row 3 = `71` from `'classAvg'` index row 2 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `82` (previous `testScore`) in index row 2 and `71` from `'classAvg'` remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 2 and 3 (no rows inbetween to be considered)

`baseScore` index row 4 = `71` from `'classAvg'` index row 2 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `85` (previous `testScore`) in index row 3 and `71` from `'classAvg'` remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 2 and 4 (index row 3 only to be considered)

`baseScore` index row 5 = `46` from `'classAvg'` index row 4 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `91` (previous `testScore`) in index row 4 and `46` from `'classAvg'`  remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 4 and 5 (no rows inbetween to be considered)

`baseScore` index row 6 = `46` from `'classAvg'` index row 4 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `63` (previous `testScore`) in index row 5 and `46` from `'classAvg'`  remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 4 and 6 (index row 5 only to be considered)

`baseScore` index row 7 = `46` from `'classAvg'` index row 4 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `72` (previous `testScore`) in index row 6 and `46` from `'classAvg'` remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 4 and 7 (index row 5-6 only to be considered)

`baseScore` index row 8 = `46` from `'classAvg'` index row 4 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `68` (previous `testScore`) in index row 7 and `46` from `'classAvg'` remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 4 and 8 (index row 5-7 only to be considered)

`baseScore` index row 9 = `46` from `'classAvg'` index row 4 because it is the highest pre-existing value less than `'testScore'` `70` (previous `testScore`) in index row 8 and `46` from `'classAvg'` remained lower than all subsequent `'testScore'` values between index row 4 and 9 (index row 5-8 only to be considered)

Hopefully that was a coherent explanation and hope that someone can help me achieve the desired output.

Comment: If on row `7` the testScore is `0.45` instead of `0.68`. What should be the result in baseScore?

Comment: If on row `7` the `testScore` is `0.45` instead of `0.68` the `baseScore` would be `NaN` because there no values in the previous 'classAvg` that are lower than this value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood you right, but you can try:

```
def state_machine():
    base_score = np.nan
    min_class_avg = np.inf
    vals = []
    while True:
        test_score, class_avg = yield base_score

        if test_score > min_class_avg:
            base_score = min_class_avg
        else:
            base_score = np.nan

        if min_class_avg > class_avg:
            min_class_avg = class_avg


s = state_machine()
next(s)

df["baseScore"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: s.send((x["testScore"], x["classAvg"])), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    datetime predictedScore  testScore  classAvg  baseScore
0 2020-07-04           0.64       0.77       NaN        NaN
1 2020-07-05           0.86       0.53       NaN        NaN
2 2020-07-06           0.79       0.82      0.71        NaN
3 2020-07-07           0.67       0.85       NaN       0.71
4 2020-07-08           0.72       0.91      0.46       0.71
5 2020-07-09           0.59       0.63       NaN       0.46
6 2020-07-10           0.71       0.72      0.69       0.46
7 2020-07-11           0.42       0.68      0.80       0.46
8 2020-07-12           0.76       0.70       NaN       0.46
9 2020-07-13           0.53       0.81       NaN       0.46
```

Comment: I have updated the narraative for the logic as the comparison between `classAvg` and `testScore` missed some crucial logic